# How to increment a value in a txt file in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I have been trying to write a batch code that will:

1. Auto execute after POST.
2. Increment a value that is suppose to represent number of the POSTs.
3. Save, display the value and restart the PC.

I have tried to write one that access a txt file for the value; however the value does not increment.

```
@echo off

echo.This script is counting the # of POSTs.

cd "C:\Users\HP-M6\Documents"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (TEST.txt)  do echo %%x

call:myPOSTTest

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (TEST.txt)  do echo %%x

echo.&pause&goto:eof

::--------------------------------------------------------
::-- Function section starts below here
::--------------------------------------------------------
-- 
:myPOSTTest    - here starts my function identified by it's label

cd "C:\Users\HP-M6\Documents"

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (TEST.txt) do (

set %x%+=1

)

goto:eof
```

Comment: You're doing a lot of echoing but where, here, do you actually change the text file?

Comment: You can try something like: `set /p var=<file.txt` - `set /a var=%var%+1` - `echo %var%>file.txt`.

Comment: The value in the text file ( x=0 ) does not change.

Comment: Variables don't survive over a reboot - your code isn't saving the value into a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (TEST.txt) do (
 set %x%+=1
)
```

What this will do is assign the contents of `TEST.txt` to the metavariable (loop-control variable) `%%x`

Then it assigns the value "1" to the user-variable "[the contents of user-variable `x`]+"

Since the user-variable `x` has not been set, this assigns `1` to the user-variable `+`.

This should be re-written

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (TEST.txt) do (
 set /a var=%%x+1
)
```

that is, assign to user-variable `var` the value read from the file into the metavariable `%%x` + 1. The `/a` modifier on the `set` means `resolve the assignment as an arithmetic expression, not a string-assignment`.

You would then need to write out the value to the file, so the replacement routine is

```dos
:myPOSTTest    - here starts my function identified by its label
cd "C:\Users\HP-M6\Documents"
for /f %%x in (TEST.txt) do (
set /a var=%%x+1
)
>TEST.txt echo %var%
goto:eof
```

Note that since there is only one token in the file, the `tokens` and `delims` phrases are redundant.

This also assumes that `TEST.TXT` already exists and has an initial content of `0`. To make this safe, the final version should be:

```dos
:myPOSTTest    - here starts my function identified by its label
cd "C:\Users\HP-M6\Documents"
if not exist TEST.txt >TEST.txt echo 0
for /f %%x in (TEST.txt) do (
set /a var=%%x+1
)
>TEST.txt echo %var%
goto:eof
```

which will create the file with an inital line of simply '0' if it doesn't already exist.

---

(minor edit) - the directory-change should be done before the file can be detected.

Comment: Thank you a billion for your awesome reply and explanation. I also need this to auto execute on a start up any suggestions??

Comment: how could I have this script auto execute on a DOS startup usb??

Comment: Simply put the batch file in the Startup. Start>Programs>startup and insert a link to the batch.

Comment: trying to execute it before I get to windows!!

Comment: assuming there is no OS.

Comment: `schtasks /create /?`

Comment: @Stephan Hi,

I have the batch script that is located on a usb floppy drive (A:\) called POSTcounter, which is autoexecuted by a modified (startnet.cmd) file that is in the Windows PE image. The script is simply incrementing a value that is the number of posts and writes the number to a txt file saved on the floppy drive. This script runs fine in windows environment command prompt and saves the txt file. However when the script is autoexecuted in WinPE the script runs but the txt file does not get updated.

Comment: @user3165643: you did a `cd C:\Users\HP-M6\Documents` before writing the txt-file. This is the location to look for it. (btw: you should use the `/d` parameter with `cd` to change the drive too) Edit: just saw your answer.

Answer (score 0):

startnet.cmd includes:

wpeinit
A:\POSTcounter.cmd

POSTcounter.cmd includes:

```
@echo off

echo. This script is counting the # of POSTs.
echo.                                        

call:myPOSTTest

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (TEST.txt)  do echo POST# %%x

echo.&pause&goto:eof


:myPOSTTest    - here starts my function identified by its label

cd "A:\"

if not exist TEST.txt >TEST.txt echo 0

for /f %%x in (TEST.txt) do (

set /a var=%%x+1

)

>TEST.txt echo %var%

goto:eof
```

Comment: Hi, I have the batch script that is located on a usb floppy drive (A:) called POSTcounter, which is autoexecuted by a modified (startnet.cmd) file that is in the Windows PE image. The script is simply incrementing a value that is the number of posts and writes the number to a txt file saved on the floppy drive. This script runs fine in windows environment command prompt and saves the txt file. However when the script is autoexecuted in WinPE the script runs but the txt file does not get updated...any suggestions???